# Office Graph API Put Files on One Drive are Corrupt

Tags: node.js, typescript, office365, onedrive

I am able to get the files as mail attachments from office 365 mail,  I am able to then create the files on one drive.  However all of the files are corrupt and cannot be opened.  I can console log the files being created and I see the information - I am not sure what the problem is.  Someone please help.  I attached the function below.

using cloud functions we invoke the office graph api.  this works, all of it works as expected but the files are all corrupt.  They do show up on one drive and are the correct size.

```
export const getAttachmentsSaveOneDrive = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context)=>{
if(context?.auth){
  // user id
  const uid = data.id as string;
  // folder id
  const folderId = data.folderId as string;
  // folder name
  const folderName = data.folderName as string;
  return await client
  .api('/users/' + uid as string +'/mailFolders/'+folderId as string+'/messages').filter("hasAttachments eq true&$select=id").get()
  .then(async(res)=>{
 
    const messagefilter = Promise.resolve([res.value]);
    
    // return messagefilter
    (await
      // return messagefilter
      messagefilter).forEach(element => {
        element.forEach(async (item:any) => {
          console.log(item.id)
           await client.api('/users/' + uid as string +'/mailFolders/'+folderId as string+'/messages/'+item.id as string+'/attachments').expand('microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item').get().then(async (res_item)=>{
        
        
          (await res_item.value).forEach(async (aitem:any) => {
      
  
              let driveItem = {
           
                "name": aitem.name as string,
                "contentType": "text/plain",
                "isInline":  aitem.isInline,
             
                "contentBytes":  aitem.contentBytes as string,
                file: {
                
                 },
                '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior': 'rename',
              }
       
              console.log('DRIVE ITEM', driveItem)
              await client.api('/users/' + uid as string +'/drive/root:/'+folderName+'/'+aitem.name+':/content').put(driveItem).then(async (res_create)=>{
                console.log('RES_CREATE', res_create)
                
             
             
            })
   
          
          });
        })
        });

      
    
    });
    
});
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forth - we ended up having to create an arrow function and return the buffer.from.  This is GCP Cloud Functions, so one will see the context.auth call - which is seeing if the user is logged in or not.

GCP Cloud Functions for us are NodeJS.  So this should work for anyone else encountering issues.

For reference - we opened a ticket on Microsoft GitHub and it was Koros that helped us realize what the issue was.

The function:

```
export const getAttachmentsSaveOneDrive = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (context ?.auth) {
    // user id
    const uid = data.id as string;
    // folder id
    const folderId = data.folderId as string;
    // folder name
    const folderName = data.folderName as string;
    return await serverclient
      .api('/users/' + uid as string + '/mailFolders/' + folderId as string + '/messages').filter("hasAttachments eq true&$select=id").get()
      .then(async (res) => {
        // console.log(res)
        // console.log('RES VALUE',res.value)
        const messagefilter = Promise.resolve([res.value]);

        // return messagefilter
        (await
          // return messagefilter
          messagefilter).forEach(element => {
          element.forEach(async (item: any) => {
            console.log(item.id)
            await serverclient.api('/users/' + uid as string + '/mailFolders/' + folderId as string + '/messages/' + item.id as string + '/attachments').expand('microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item').get().then(async (res_item) => {
              // console.log('ITEM', res_item.value)

              (await res_item.value).forEach(async (aitem: any) => {
                serverclient.api('/users/' + uid as string + '/mailFolders/' + folderId as string + '/messages/' + item.id as string + '/attachments/' + aitem.id).get().then(async (item$) => {
                  console.log('NAME', aitem.name)
                  console.log('FILE VALUE', item$)

                  let driveItem = {

                    "contentBytes": item$.contentBytes,

                  }
                  const decodeBase64String = (str: any) => {
                    return Buffer.from(str, 'base64')
                  }

                  console.log('DRIVE ITEM', driveItem)
                  await serverclient.api('/users/' + uid as string + '/drive/root:/' + folderName + '/' + aitem.name + ':/content').put(decodeBase64String(driveItem.contentBytes)).then(async (res_create) => {
                    console.log('RES_CREATE', res_create)
                  })
                })



              });
            })
          });



        });

      });
  }
});
```

the GitHub ticket:
[https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/1166][1]